# how to generate excel file from the array using npm package in node js?

Tags: arrays, node.js, excel

I am go for the generate excel file using node.js. and i have used for npm package.and i want to generate excel file from the array to excel file.but how can do that i have no idea so any one know how can do that then please help me.
**Note : i have include like this var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');**.

here this my array =>

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');.
var  Array = [];
Array.push({ fullName: 'love',
            username: 'lo.ve632',
            biography: '',
            externalUrl: '',
            followerCount: 10,
            followingCount: 107,
           mediaCount: 0 },
         { fullName: 'abc',
           username: '@bc',
           biography: '',
           externalUrl: '',
           followerCount: 288,
           followingCount: 261,
           mediaCount: 0 },
        { fullName: 'xyz',
          username: 'xyz',
          biography: '#This is my ',
         externalUrl: '',
         followerCount: 234,
          followingCount: 282,
         mediaCount: 17 })
```

Here i have write this code =>

```
  const workSheetsFromBuffer = xlsx.parse(fs.readFileSync());
 var buffer = xlsx.build([{ name: "mySheetName", data: Array}]);
```

but here i have no idea where to store my excel file and how can generate file so please help me any one know than.

Comment: you can easily create & download ..excel using html table  or json on client side only...no need to go for server side...it is overkill...should I show some examples

Comment: @RohitasBehera sorry but i want complasary go with this code so i want examples with my code so can you give me an help me please

Comment: You can use the buffer to create a file. `fs.writeFile(filename, yourbuffer, callback)`